# Netsuite "Invalid assignment left-hand side" when submitting records

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying desesperatly to update a field in NetSuite (custom record) linked to an inboundshipment,

```
var record = nlapiLoadRecord("inboundshipment", 74);
record.setFieldValue("custrecord_sent_to_jb", "test");
nlapiSubmitRecord(record);
var nlobj = record;
return nlobj;
```

When I comment the nlapiSubmitRecord(record), the record is returned updated in the JSON, but not the in NetSuite

I don't know why I receive "Invalid assignment left-hand side" message when I submit the record (I have tried also in SS2.0, the problem occurs at var NSID = tran.save())

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType restlet
 */

//Use: Update NS inboundshipment / itemfulfillment with data (context) that is passed from JB

define(['N/record'], function(record) //use the record module
{
    function postData(context)
    {
        //
        var tran = record.load({type:context.TransactionType, id:context.TransactionNumber});
        var message = context.Date + "|" + context.SED;
        log.debug("RESTlet JB","loaded the tran with NSID: " + context.id);

        //set some body fields
        tran.setValue("custrecord_sent_to_jb", message);

        //save the record
        var NSID = tran.save();
        log.debug("RESTlet JB","saved the record with NSID: " + NSID);
        return NSID; //success return the ID to JB
    }

    //get and post both required
    return {
      get : function (){return "received";},
      post : postData //
    };
});
```

The custom record:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there are other scripts, most probably User Event scripts deployed on the context.TransactionType value.  Since this is a RESTlet, it will trigger User Event scripts deployed on the record.

Comment: Thank you @Rusty, you are totally right, it was due to another userevent.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do a submitField? Saves you a lot of trouble.